# Multi-threaded event broker in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple multi-threaded event broker in my application that exposes two methods and an interface:

```
interface IEventHandler extends Runnable
{
    public setEvent(Event e);
}

public <T extends Event> void Subscribe(Class<T> eventType, IEventHandler handler);

public <T extends Event> Publish(T event);
```

Publish finds the appropriate handler, sets the event, and spawns a thread to run it:

```
IEventHandler handler = findHandlerForTheEventType();
handler.setEvent(event);
new Thread(handler);
```

What I'm worried about (this hasn't happened yet but I'm pretty sure it might) that the same event will be fired simultaneously and the eventHandler would be disturbed with `setEvent` in a middle of a run. Is there some design pattern to solve this?

Comment: when such a clash happens, do you want the last event dropped or delayed until the current thread is finished?

Comment: @ChrisK I'd rather it to be either delayed or handled simultaneously, certainly not dropped

Comment: your example already has it invoke the handler simulaneously..

Comment: @ChrisK By recognizing that the handler is busy and creating and cloning the handler. Now that I think about it maybe I should clone the handler every time the event is fired :)

Comment: if there is state in the handler, then clone or block using a synchronized lock.  If it is stateless, then it could just be allowed to run concurrently.  You are the best one to judge which approach is best here.

Comment: @ChrisK The event itself is the state I guess. Every time an event is fired, a new instance of the event is being created

Comment: One suggestion though, use a thread pool rather than creating and throwing away new threads

Comment: @Shmoopy Then you can simply change your `IEventHandler` to have `processEvent(Event e)` instead of being a runnable.

Comment: It would depend on how setEvent operates internally. Since the above code is sketchy, not sure how you have designed the handler. However, in this case we try to make the handler thread-safe i.e. it must not have any extrinsic state that can be changed during thread execution by the thread. In your case, perhaps it is better to set the event and start the thread from the handler and setEvent be synchronized.

Comment: wht you exactly needs an event Queuing mechanism. right?